# How to parse unformated XML from a string in Python

Tags: xml, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, xml-parsing, amazon-route53

I would like to fetch all records in a zone on **AWS**. . The result of `get_records()` is not completely XML format. I would like to parse **XML** from a string(Domain name and IP address). Am I doing something wrong? Can somebody help me on this please

Example: XML string `<Record:test-example.com.:A:0.0.0.0>`

```
import boto.route53.connection
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

conn = boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id = 'xxxx',aws_secret_access_key = 'xxxx')
zone = conn.get_zone('<example>.com')
records = zone.get_records()
for i in records:
    root = ET.fromstring(i)
    print(root)
```

Error:

```
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
TypeError: Parse() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not Record
```

Comment: Check out the `lxml` library, specifically the `etree.fromstring()` function.

Comment: @VergeA: any other alternative? I'm using Python2.x. Getting so many dependencies while trying to install `lxml` (all those dependencies are not available for my Python version). Looks like it's only works with Python3 efficiently.

Comment: "Only works with Python3 efficiently" is absolutely untrue.  Which version of 2 are you using?  If you have 2.7, you can find a precompiled version with dependencies here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Comment: Also, your error above actually seems to be stemming from the fact that the `i` that you pass to the ET.fromstring() function is of type `Record`.  You should convert it to a string/extract any text content from your record first.

Comment: @VergeA: Thanks for the advice. I sorted it out.